# Аутентификация в микросервисе при помощи feign?

Tags: java, spring, oauth, микросервисы

У меня есть микросервисный проект, я начал использовать FeignClien  в нем. Но появилась проблема, если я авторизировался на одном сервисе и с этого сервиса иду на другой, то на другом мне также нужно авторизироваться. Код подобного приложения можно найти [здесь](https://github.com/Pryanic/OAuth) 
Как решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 1):

Предположим, что **аутентификация происходит по токену**, который **передается в хедере Authorization**, а объект **Authentication** строится таким образом, что сам токен можно получить вызвава **getDetails()**. Тогда нужно добавить бин класса **feign.RequestInterceptor** к конфигурации:

```
    @Bean
    RequestInterceptor feignRequestInterceptor(){
        return  requestTemplate -> requestTemplate.header(
                "Authorization",
                 SecurityContextHolder
                    .getContext()
                        .getAuthentication()
                            .getDetails()
                                .toString()
        );
    }
```

Похожий вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40262132/how-to-add-a-request-interceptor-to-a-feign-client